# Propositional Logic and Redundancy

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus, philosophy, decision-trees

The Dutch philosopher [Emanuel Rutten](https://www.gjerutten.nl/) wrote an article, titled [Dissolving the Scandal of Propositional Logic?](https://www.gjerutten.nl/DissolvingScandalPropositionalLogic_Rutten.pdf), about the philosophical problems with the [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#Philosophical_problems_with_material_conditional). From his article, we quote the following as an example that is true in propositional logic but **sounds illogical** in common language:

*[2] Brigitte can mix green with yellow paint
OR Brigitte can mix green with blue paint.*

In the formalism of propositional logic it says: $(P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R)$ with $R = P \wedge Q$.
A truth table shows that this expression is a tautology.
Now, from David Gries, "Compiler Construction for Digital Computers", John Wiley & Sons, 1971, we alternatively have:

```
c OR d   is defined by  IF c THEN TRUE  ELSE  d
c AND d  is defined by  IF c THEN   d   ELSE FALSE
  NOT c  is defined by  IF c THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
c ==> d  is defined by  IF c THEN   d   ELSE TRUE
c        is defined by  IF c THEN TRUE  ELSE FALSE
```

Thus, in a sequential sense - according to Gries - the tautology $(P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R)$ reads as follows.

```
if (if P then R else TRUE) then TRUE else (if Q then R else TRUE)
```

In most programming languages boolean expressions indeed seem to be subject to "lazy evaluation" of the above kind.
Therefore we can replace the abovementioned *sequential* expression by its combinatorical equivalent again:
$((\neg P) \vee R) \vee ((\neg Q) \vee R_{\_}(R))$.
With a little adjustment for the second variable $R$: the function $R_{\_}(R)$ is identical to $R$
but it contains an **alarm** message in addition, namely: ' observed! '.
A little program in Pascal shall make clearer what's going on here:

```
program Rutten;

function r_(r : boolean) : boolean;
begin
  Write(' observed! ');
  r_ := r;
end;

procedure test;
var
  p,q,r : boolean;
  k : integer;
begin
  Writeln('P':6,'Q':6,'R':6,'(P=>R)v(Q=>R)':16);
  Writeln('-----------------------------------');
  for k := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    p := ((k div 2) = 0);
    q := ((k mod 2) = 0);
    r := (p and q);
    Writeln(p:6,q:6,r:6,((not p) or r) or ((not q) or r_(r)):12);
  { if (if p then r else true) then true else (if q then r else true) }
  end;
end;

begin
  test;
end.
```

Output (mind the *absence* of the alarm):

```
     P     Q     R   (P=>R)v(Q=>R)
-----------------------------------
  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE        TRUE
  TRUE FALSE FALSE        TRUE
 FALSE  TRUE FALSE        TRUE
 FALSE FALSE FALSE        TRUE
```

The point is: *the message ' observed! ' will never be observed!*
The function $R_{\_}(R)$ is not executed in any way; it is like the program statement is simply not present.
So what's left is this: $((\neg P) \vee R) \vee (\neg Q)$. In common language that is:

*[2] Brigitte can mix green with yellow paint
OR Brigitte has no blue paint.*

Which sounds anyway more reasonable than the original statement.
It is also seen that the expression $(P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R)$ is logically equivalent with this one: $((\neg P) \vee R) \vee ((\neg Q) \vee R) \equiv ((\neg P) \vee (\neg Q) \vee (R \vee R))$. The last instance of $R$ is obviously **redundant**.
Still anoher way of looking at our problem shall be presented.
For ease of notation, let's replace TRUE by $1$ and FALSE by $0$ in $(P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R)$ with $R = (P \wedge Q)$.
Then, with the sequential interpretation and all possibilities covered:

```
if (if P then R else 1) then 1 else (if Q then R else 1) : in general
if (if 0        else 1) then 1            [    ]         : P = 0
if (if 1 then 0       )        else (if 0 [    ] else 1) : P = 1, Q = 0
if (if 1 then 1       ) then 1            [    ]         : P = 1, Q = 1
```

So for the second instance of $R$ we have, with all possible (0,1) specifications, empty spots [ ];
it is like the second instance of $R$ it is not there at all!
The accompanying [Flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) is in concordance with this observation:

[image]
As a second example, consider the tautology $(P \Rightarrow Q) \vee (Q \Rightarrow P)$.

The sequential version is, with 0 = FALSE and 1 = TRUE and all possibilities exhausted:

```
if (if P then Q else 1) then 1 else (if Q then P else 1) : in general
if (if 0        else 1) then 1            [    ]         : P = 0
if (if 1 then 0       )        else (if 0 [    ] else 1) : P = 1, Q = 0
if (if 1 then 1       ) then 1            [    ]         : P = 1, Q = 1
```

Empty spots [ ] again. So the second instance of P is obviously **redundant**.
As is clear as well from the [Flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart):

[image]

Not all propositional [tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) contain redundancies.
Time to present a counter example: $(P \Rightarrow Q) \Rightarrow (\neg Q \Rightarrow \neg P)$.

```
if (if P then Q else 1) then (if -Q then -P else 1) else 1 : in general
if (if 0        else 1) then (if  1 then  1       )        : P = 0, Q = 0
if (if 0        else 1) then (if  0         else 1)        : P = 0, Q = 1
if (if 1 then 0       )                             else 1 : P = 1, Q = 0
if (if 1 then 1       ) then (if  0         else 1)        : P = 1, Q = 1
```

All instances of P and Q are decidable, none of these is redundant.

The tautology   IF(IF P THEN Q) THEN (IF NOT Q THEN NOT P)   is acceptable in common language as well.
In the [Flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) all decisions are useful:

[image]

**Question**. When considering tautologies in **Propositional Logic**
that sound "not good" in the logic of common language, does our notion of **Redundancy**, developed so far, provide a clue for dissolving that issue?

Comment: Are you sure you quoted the "Brigitte" example at the beginning correctly? "Brigitte can mix green with yellow paint" isn't a conditional statement, so I don't see how it turned into $(P\implies R)$ a couple of lines later. Also, the quoted statement about Brigitte's paint-mixing ability doesn't sound illogical in common language.

Comment: @AndreasBlass. As you can check out, the Brigitte example is a __literal quote__ from the article by Emanuel Rutten. But perhaps it could have been formulated better as follows: _if Brigitte has yellow paint then she can mix green OR if Brigitte has blue paint then she can mix green_. I think this may solve your first issue. But I still find that the quoted statement _does_ sounds illogical in common language.

Comment: From Rutten's article: "[1] If Brigitte has yellow paint and blue paint, then Brigitte can mix green, [2] Brigitte can mix green with yellow paint or Brigitte can mix green with blue paint." He suggests that it is somehow illogical that [2] should follow from [1] even though it may be a tautology. IMHO it may be counter-intuititive, but NOT illogical. Forgetting about the colour-wheel from art class for the moment, [1] does not strictly rule out different ways to mix green paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rutten's own article](https://www.gjerutten.nl/DissolvingScandalPropositionalLogic_Rutten.pdf):

> [1] If Brigitte has yellow paint and blue paint, then Brigitte can mix
> green;
>  [2] Brigitte can mix green with yellow paint or Brigitte
> can mix green with blue paint.
>
> Now, **the logical form of this argument is to be formally rendered in
> the calculus of propositional logic as follows**:
>  [1*] P ∧ Q →
> R;
>  [2*] (P → R) ∨ (Q → R).
>
> Here P = “Brigitte has yellow
> paint”, Q = “Brigitte has blue paint” and R = “Brigitte can mix
> green”. As I show in my lecture, **the calculus of propositional logic
> does in fact render** the  argument form [1*]-[2*] and thus **the
> argument [1]-[2] logically valid.** This is how I arrived at  the
> scandal of propositional logic. After all, it is certainly a real
> scandal that **the calculus of  propositional logic forces us to
> accept argument [1]-[2] as a valid logical consequence.**

There is no scandal, because the given argument [1]$\Rightarrow$[2] is in fact logically *invalid*, as per our intuition. Rutten has merely wrongly formalised it as [1*]$\Rightarrow$[2*] , so
is mistaken in making the above boldfaced claims.

In propositional calculus, the statement “Brigitte can mix green with yellow paint” is an atomic proposition (let's symbolise it as $Y);$ Rutten has mistranslated it as $P\to R$ (i.e., if Brigitte has yellow paint, then Brigitte can mix green). The correct translation of the given argument is actually $$
P\land Q\to R\implies Y\lor B,$$ which is unsurprisingly invalid.

In first-order logic, due to the ambiguity of the statement “Brigitte can mix green”, the given argument has three possible translations, each of which is unsurprisingly also invalid: \begin{align}\Big(Py\land Pb\to\forall c\:Mgc\Big)\implies Mgy \lor Mgb\tag1\\
\Big(Py\land Pb\to Mgy \lor Mgb\Big)\implies Mgy \lor Mgb\tag2\\
\Big(Py\land Pb\to\exists c\:Mgc\Big)\implies Mgy \lor Mgb.\tag3\end{align}

---

Regarding the redundancy mentioned in the Question:

the argument $$\Big(P ∧ Q → R\Big)\to\Big((P → R) ∨ (Q → R)\Big)$$ is [indeed](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((P%7E1Q%7E5R)%7E5((P%7E5R)%7E2(Q%7E5R)))%7E4(P%7E1Q%7E5P%7E2Q)) logically equivalent to the argument $$\Big(P ∧ Q\Big)\to \Big(P ∨ Q\Big),$$ so $R$ is a red herring, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for giving attention to this question! I see hat you have edited my question and I can live with those edits, except for a few; I hope you can live with the latter.

Comment: @HandeBruijn Haha, I'd edited only the first paragraph! If it looks like I'd edited more than that, it's because your original HTML formatting somehow got broken by the StackExchange system forcing me to manually replace a few instances of strings like `<p>` with actual paragraph breaks (in order to preserve how the Question looked). -)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the author has made a little mistake while trying to reproduce the problem from the
[article](https://www.gjerutten.nl/DissolvingScandalPropositionalLogic_Rutten.pdf) by Emanuel Rutten.
What's actually in there is this:
\begin{cases}
\mbox{[1*] } P \wedge Q \Rightarrow R, \\
\mbox{[2*] } (P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R).
\end{cases}
Here $P =$ “Brigitte has yellow paint”, $Q =$ “Brigitte has blue paint” and $R =$ “Brigitte can mix green”.
The calculus of propositional logic does render the argument form [1*]-[2*] logically valid.
The above may be concisely written as:
$$
((P \wedge Q) \Rightarrow R) \Rightarrow ((P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R))
$$
Which is slightly different from what's stated in the question, where $\;R = (P \wedge Q)\;$ or $\;R \Leftrightarrow
(P \wedge Q)\;$, where it should have been $\;R \Leftarrow (P \wedge Q)\;$.
With the sequential interpretation, as explained in the question, it reads, step by step:
$$
\mbox{ if }(P \wedge Q \Rightarrow R) \mbox{ then } (P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R) \mbox { else } 1\\
(P \wedge Q \Rightarrow R) \; \equiv \; (\mbox{ if } (\mbox{ if } P \mbox{ then } Q \mbox { else } 0) \mbox{ then } R \mbox { else } 1)\\
(P \Rightarrow R) \vee (Q \Rightarrow R) \; \equiv \; (\mbox{ if } (\mbox{ if } P \mbox{ then } R \mbox { else } 1) \mbox{ then } 1 \mbox { else } (\mbox{ if } Q \mbox{ then } R \mbox { else } 1))
$$
Flow chart and specification for all (0,1) values of (P,Q,R) are slightly more complicated than before.

But the end-result is the same: the last instance of R is **redundant** (: $\color{red}{\mbox{red box}}$ [ ] ).

[image]

```
if (if (if P then Q else 0) then R else 1) then (if (if P then R else 1) then 1 else (if Q then R else 1)) else 1 : general
if (if (if 0        else 0)        else 1) then (if (if 0        else 1) then 1            [    ]                 : P = 0
if (if (if 1 then 0       )        else 1) then (if (if 1 then 0       )        else (if 0 [    ] else 1))        : P = 1 , Q = 0 , R = 0
if (if (if 1 then 0       )        else 1) then (if (if 1 then 1       ) then 1            [    ]                 : P = 1 , Q = 0 , R = 1
if (if (if 1 then 1       ) then 0                                                         [    ]          else 1 : P = 1 , Q = 1 , R = 0
if (if (if 1 then 1       ) then 1       ) then (if (if 1 then 1       ) then 1            [    ]                 : P = 1 , Q = 1 , R = 1
```

LATE EDIT. Further elaboration of Question & Answer in:

- #### About an article by Jeroen Valk